# How do I get value from a nested list with reflection?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a nested list called filterTarget.

Example about content:

```
filterTarget = { Id: 1
InventoryDescription: {Type: "Machine", Code: "1/1", Description: "1", Category: "1", StockCode: "1", …}
InventoryRecordDetails: []
Length: "1"
Life: "04.02.2019"
Location: null
Model: "1" }
```

The example I want to get the value of Code of InventoryDescription.

I wrote this code for two layers but it's looking dirty and insufficient. And it's not general.

```
filterTarget = filterTarget
          .Where(x =>  x.GetType()  
                        .GetProperty(fieldval1)
                        .PropertyType
                        .GetProperty(fieldval2)
                        .GetValue(x.GetType()
                                   .GetProperty(fieldval1)
                                   .GetValue(x))
                        .ToString()?
                        .ToLower() == deger)
          .ToList();
```

How do I get value from a nested list with reflection and linq?

Comment: What is nested here? You do have nested objects inside one-dimensional array?

Comment: wow, 1) does the code do what you expect it to do? 2) could you provide more context? the classes with the respective properties would be really nice to reproduce the problem

Comment: You might add the declaration. It will help...

Comment: Your declaration of `filterTarget` shows that it is an object instead of a list. (assuming a JSON notation)

Comment: @J.vanLangen hi, it's only example about content.

Comment: are you looking for a recursive way of diving into the deepest level? or do you want to specify the level? what exactly do you mean by "And it's not general."?

Comment: Why are we using reflection again?

Comment: @MongZhu I want to specify the level. I have level info. The user sends this info.

Comment: with my solution the level will be determined by the amount of propertynames that you give to the method

Comment: how does you level info look like? do you have a number ?

Comment: @MongZhu I have the ordered property string. Example; InventoryDescription.Type etc.

Comment: can you please post this string as a real and compileable c# example like `string propertystring = "... here goes your stuff ..."`

Comment: @MongZhu hey thanks I found the answer with your help. I will share now.

Comment: so did my answer help you? or can I simply delete it again?

Comment: @MongZhu hey look. I shared the answer. let part at your answer helped me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a linq solution then `let` would be your friend:

```
filterTarget = (from f in filterTarget
                let temp = f.GetType().GetProperty(fieldval1).GetValue(f)
                let temp2 = temp.GetType().GetProperty(fieldval2).GetValue(temp)
                where temp2.ToString().ToLower() == deger
                select f).ToList();
```

But personnaly I find it rather unreadable. A normal loop with an appropriate if-condition would be much more maintainable:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FilterMyList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string fieldval1, string fieldval2, string deger)
{
    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        var nesteValue1 = element.GetType().GetProperty(fieldval1).GetValue(element);
        var nestedValue2 = nesteValue1.GetType().GetProperty(fieldval2).GetValue(nesteValue1);
        if (nestedValue2.ToString().ToLower() == deger)
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a more general way that uses recursion to dive into your nested object. You need to provide the exact amount of propertynames and it has to match the levels of nestedness:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FilterMyListRecursive<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string searchpattern, params string [] propertynames) where T: class
{
    foreach (var element in list)
    {       
        if (TryNestedRecursiveDescend(element, searchpattern, propertynames))
        {
            yield return element;
        }       
    }
}

private bool TryNestedRecursiveDescend<T>(T obj, string searchpattern, params string [] propertynames) where T: class
{   
    var nestedValue = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertynames.First()).GetValue(obj);
    // if you are at the lowest level that you can check
    if (fieldvalues.Length == 1)
    {       
        return nestedValue.ToString().ToLower() == searchpattern;
    }
    else
    {
        // recursive call with the remaining propertynames
        return TryNestedDescend(nestedValue, searchpattern, propertynames.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filterTarget is my nested List.

field is ordered property string.

```
  filterTarget = (from f in filterTarget
  let temp = GetPropertyValue(f, Field)
  where temp?.ToString().ToLower() == "deger"
  select f).ToList();

  private static object GetPropertyValue<T>(T filterTarget, string field)
  {
   string[] fields = field.Split('.');
   object value = filterTarget;
   fields?.ToList().ForEach(p =>
   {
      value = value.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(value);
   });

    return value;
  }
```

Comment: considering the information inside your post, it is difficult to follow how your own solution solves your problem. This post (at the moment) will not be helpfull to any other user. Why da hack do you split by `.` ? there is no information in your question that would justify this approach

Comment: Don't use `List.ForEach` to replace `foreach` - it isn't an improvement.